# Make that script only work while right mouse is pressed

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Please somebody could make this script only work while right mouse is pressed? Thank you!!

Here is the code below:

```
--This game needs to match the proper X-axis jitter

X = 0  --X-axis jitter,The higher the value, the more applicable it is to C8 and Evo guns
Y = 4  --Y-axis down,This is matched with the x-axis adjustment
sleep = 14   --At the moment, I think 15 milliseconds is the best


function OnEvent(event, arg)
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2) then
        A = true
        ClearLog()
        OutputLogMessage("On\n")
end

if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
        A = false
        ClearLog()
        OutputLogMessage("Off\n")
end

        
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and A==true) then
    repeat
        MoveMouseRelative(X, Y)
        X = -X   --crux
        Sleep(sleep)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
end
end
```

Thank You!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--This game needs to match the proper X-axis jitter

X = 0  --X-axis jitter,The higher the value, the more applicable it is to C8 and Evo guns
Y = 4  --Y-axis down,This is matched with the x-axis adjustment
sleep = 14   --At the moment, I think 15 milliseconds is the best

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(X, Y)
         X = -X   --crux
         Sleep(sleep)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) or not IsMouseButtonPressed(3) 
   end
end
```